# Accessing current item from ListView data source

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, datasource

I figured this wouldn't be too difficult to do, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it. Is there a way to easily access the current item from a ListView data source? For instance, you can easily evaluate the current item's properties using `Eval("propertyName")`, but is there a way to access the object itself?

And if this isn't possible, what I ultimately want to do is get the Type of the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **FindControl** Method.

For example,

```
int index=0; // obtain the index of an item. 
TextBox num = (TextBox)ListView1.Items[index].FindControl("numTextBox");
```